# Setting up view returns null pointer when location settings request is refused?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-location-services

I am having this issue where the `Views` in my `Fragment` returns null when the user refuses to turn on their `Location` settings in a pop up. I can't seem to reference any of the `Views` in the `Fragment`. I would imagine it is because the popup dialog for the `Location` request `View` supercedes my `Fragment View` but I can't figure out how I can access the `Views` within my `Fragment`. Here is my attempt:

```
private View fragmentView;
private View progressOverlay;
private View noPostsView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (fragmentView == null) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.posts_tab, container, false);
        setupActivity(savedInstanceState);
        progressOverlay = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);
        progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        noPostsView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.no_posts_layout);
        setupLocation();
    }
    return fragmentView;
}

private void setupLocation() {
    Context context = getContext();
    if(locationService == null) {
        locationService = new LocationService(context, new LocationUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void canReceiveLocationUpdates() {

            }

            @Override
            public void cannotReceiveLocationUpdates() {
                createSettingsRequest();
                //well we know we cant receive updates so we have to create a settings request
            }

            //update location to our servers for tracking purpose
            @Override
            public void updateLocation(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    //Populate Recycler View
                    databaseQuery.getPublicPosts(location, progressOverlay, fragmentView, getContext());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void updateLocationName(String localityName, Location location) {
                locationService.stopLocationUpdates();
            }
        });
        locationService.startUpdates();
    }
}

private void createSettingsRequest() {
    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(locationService.mGoogleApiClient
                    , builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_LOCATION);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        FirebaseCrash.report(e);
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        setupNoPostsView();
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

private void setupNoPostsView() {
    progressOverlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    noPostsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_posts_feed);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    TextView noPosts = (TextView) noPostsView.findViewById(R.id.no_posts_text);
    noPosts.setText(R.string.permission_location_rationale);
}
```

I simply want call `setupNoPostsView` if the user clicks `No` on allowing `Location Services` but for whatever reason, the `progressOverlay View` keeps returning `null` when I try to set the `Visibility = View.GONE`. Any idea on how I can get around this?

Update here is my layout as requested by the first answer:

Fragment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/posts_tab"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_news_feed" tools:context=".news_feed">

    <include layout="@layout/include_progress_overlay"/>

    <include layout="@layout/no_posts"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rv_posts_feed"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

</FrameLayout>
```

no_posts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/no_posts_layout"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/no_posts_text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Are you calling the correct layout? Have you defined the activity in the manifest file?

Comment: what NPE exactly - can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the method

> status.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), REQUEST_LOCATION);

is calling a new activity, provided by google play services, that is showing the dialog to turn on location settings. Let's call A your activity and B the one provided by google play services. Probably, when B is created, A is destroyed, because of memory pressure or because you have changed the orientation of the device. When you select 'refuse' on B, the callback 'onActivityResult' is called before the view is recreated by Android (this is in fact possible). So...you have to manage this case in a different way, for example setting a sort of flag on your onAcvityResult. Example:

```
private Integer myResult = null;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (REQUEST_LOCATION == requestCode) {
        View root = getView();
        if (root != null) { // Consider also isResumed()
            // you can operate on your views
            applyLogicForResult(resultCode);
        } else {
            myResult = resultCode;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { // Consider also onResume()
    if (myResult != null) {
        applyLogicForResult(myResult);
        myResult = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks so much! With some tinkering I got it to work actually. I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

1. What kind of layout are you using? You can use a frame layout for the fragment. (You need to recall one thing that frame layout can display only one child layout at a time)
2. Put the contents in this frame layout and also you have to add one more layout i.e is the text view layout which says that location not available.At the start the view properties of this text view should be hidden.

   ```
   <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/rv"
      />
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/error"
          android:layout_gravity="left|center|right"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:visibility="gone"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No location available"
          android:textAlignment="center" />
   </FrameLayout>
   ```

Something similar to this..^

3. Now coming to the java code

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       switch (requestCode) {
           // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
           case REQUEST_LOCATION:
               switch (resultCode) {
                   case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                       break;
                   case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                       setupNoPostsView();
                       break;
               }
               break;
       }
   }



   private void setupNoPostsView() 
   {
       RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.rv_posts_feed);
       recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
   ```

Comment: Hey, I actually did as you specified. I uploaded my XML files that are necessary in this and I still keep getting the NPE exception. Any help would be appreciated.